# Help with this probability density function

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

(a) Verify that$ f $is a PDF. That is,  check that $f(x)$ is always non-negative and that the area under $f(x)$ is $1$. My understanding is that if $a < x < b $then it is $1/b-a$ so the area would have to be non negative, the graph would look somewhat like this
[image]

$a$ being $20$ and $b$ being $40$. $1/20 = .05$ which is non negative but I am not sure how to prove it is $1$?

(b) Find the $CDF$ of $X$, $F(y)$, for all $y$.
Finding the $PDF$ first,

| x  | P(x)|
| ---| --- |
| 20 | .1  |
| 21 | .1  |
| 22 | .1  |
And so on

So $CDF$ would be
| x       | F(x)|
| ---     | --- |
| x<20    | .1  |
| 20<=x<21| .2  |
| 21<=x<22| .3  |
and so on

(c) Find $P(30<X<50)$.
Since $(20<=X<40)$ is $1/20$ would $P(30<X<50)$ just be $1/30$?

(d)Find expected value of X
$.1*20+.1*21....+.1*40$ (I have not calculated it yet but I believe this is the correct form)

It also asks to find standard deviation and variance, but as long as I am correct thus far I do not need help figuring it out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: My P(x) as well as F(x) comes out in table form when I edit and review, I am not sure why it is formatting like that when it prints out, I am also fairly new to MathJax/markdown so any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you find the area of a rectangle?

Comment: To compute the "CDF", we want $g(x_0)=P(x\le x_0)$.  For example, for $x_0 \le 20,\quad  g(x_0)=0.$

Comment: What is $g(x_0)$ when $x_0 \ge 40?$

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{1}{b-a},$ for $a < x < b.$ Not $1/b - a.$ Then area of rectangle by geometry is $h\times w = \frac{1}{b-a} \times (b-a) = 1.$ // $P(30 < X < 50) = P(30 < X < 40) = 1/2.$ // $E(X) = 30,$ balance point of density.

Comment: Your result in (d) may be the "correct answer" which agrees with @BruceET's answer.  The "correct" formula is $\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{1}{20} \int_{20}^{40}  x \, dx $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your calculations are for if f is discrete, but here f is continuous.

(a) To show that f(x) is a pdf, you have to verify that the area under it is 1. You can do it like this: $\int_{20}^{40}\frac{1}{20}dx=\frac 1 {20}[x]_{20}^{40}=\frac 1 {20}(40-20)=1$ Since the area under the pdf integrates to 1, it is a valid pdf. Or you can observe that the pdf is a rectangle that has height y=1/20 for 20<x<40 and is flat y=0 when x is not in that range. So the pdf is given by the area of the rectangle, 20*1/20=1. Your picture is right, now you need to multiply b-a by 1/(b-a).

(b) The cdf F(y) is the probability that X is less than y, aka P(X<y). For a uniform distribution, it is given by

$$F(y)=\begin{cases}0&y<a\\
\frac{y-a}{b-a}&a\le y<b\\1&y\ge b\end{cases}$$

Here we have

$$F(y)=\begin{cases}0&y<20\\
\frac{y-20}{40-20}&20\le y<40\\1&y\ge40\end{cases}$$

This is a flat line at 0 when y<20, a line with constant slope $\frac 1{20}$ when 20<y<40, and then a flat line at 1 when y>40.

(c) $P(30<X<50)=P(30<X<40)+\underbrace{P(40<X<50)}_{=0}=(40-30)*1/20=\frac 1 2$

where the second term is 0 because X has 0 density above 40.

(d) The expected value or mean of a continuous uniform distribution is $\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{20+40}{2}=30$. It is the tick that is between the two ends.

Comment: So then to find standard deviation, would it just be 0 given that the EV is 30? and variance it would just be 30/20?

Comment: For a continuous uniform distribution, variance is $\frac 1 {12}(b-a)^2$. It can be derived from $Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$. Sd is the square root of that.